Ubuntu 24.04 LTS does not wake up or repond after being idle for some time
I am using a Dell Inspiron Laptop 15R 5537 with 2TB Samsung SSD, 16 GB ram and Secure boot enabled. It was running smoothly on windows 10.
Few days back I had clean installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on the laptop.  I had disabled auto suspend while plugged in and enabled it on battery mode (after 1 hour). Screen blank was set at 10 mins.
The issue is once I lock the laptop and leave it for some time the screen goes blank as usual and the laptop does not wake up on pressing any key or moving the mouse.
The inbuilt keyboard, its capslock, track pad and lights for harddrive/PC access does not function.
Only the power indicator light, WiFi indicator light on the laptop are on and the laptop fan keeps running. The screen remains blank.
I tried plugging a hard drive, nothing happened to the laptop but I can feel the portable harddrive running. CD tray opens as usual, but the Laptop does not wake after putting in a CD.
Pressing the power button did not help, but when I long press the power button the laptop force shuts down as usual and also boots normally after that.
Laptop wakes up and shows the password screen when I press the keyboard immediately after locking it, but  if I leave the laptop locked for some time then it does not respond at all.
I tried reinstalling Ubuntu once again, but still the same.
So i tried again after disabling the screen blank and auto-suspend options completely. I also tried to copy almost 1.5Tb of data to keep the laptop active. But the same issue still persists, the laptop got frozen when it was kept unattended and unlocked for some and now the only difference is the screen is on with the default desktop interface. None of the keys are working. I had to force restart again by long pressing the power button. I am not sure why this is happening after disabling screen blank and auto-suspend. The data transfer also stopped when the laptop got frozen.
I have been using windows computers for around 25 years, but my knowledge in Linux is very limited (including the commands used in terminal).
I think the issue is related to saving power while the laptop is idle/locked, but I am unable to troubleshoot using the user interface in settings. I tried searching google as well as AskUbuntu.com and couldn't find almost similar issue.
If anyone knows what is happening plz help me to make necessary changes in the laptop.
Thanks 

I can confirm that on HP Elitebook 840 G5 the same thing happens. After the screen switches off it is impossible to wake it up. The computer is not crashed, just runs without a screen. Ubuntu 24.04. Probably a bug somewhere.

This happens to me on a HP EliteBook 840 G8 w\ Ubuntu 24.04, but only at the login screen! Still trying to figure out why

After having similar problems with my Acer Swift 314-54 laptop my final setup is:

Disable Secure Boot
Turn The Screen Off: Never
Dim Screen: On
Automatic Power Saver: On
Automatic Suspend: 15 minutes
Power Button Behavior: Suspend

I'm using a sdd with full encryption.
So apparently the problem arises when you combine Suspend with Secure Boot in Ubuntu.
I had similar trouble in Windows 10 with some default Intel HD drivers.
The error was fixed once I installed windows 11. But that is not the system I want to use.
Update: After further testing, I have managed to get it to work with Secure Boot enabled.
But if I activate screen shutdown the error persists. Therefore I do not use this option.
Note: My swap is a file and not a partition.

Thanks a lot for the suggestion. Really appreciate it.
Secure boot was disabled by default in the bios, and i had manually enabled it during my second reinstallation of Ubuntu. I had done it only because the Device security in the settings menu showed that the option was disabled and mentioned as not secure.
I never had to change the default bios settings in any Microsoft Windows OS installations till now, except changing boot priority while installing OS.

Currently, i made one more change in the bios. I enabled 'USB wake' in the Dell bios which was disabled by default and i have re-enabled screen blank and auto suspend after that.
So far my laptop did not crash or freeze during screen lock or screen blank or auto-suspend.
So, my current settings are:

Enabled 'Secure Boot' in bios
Enabled 'USB Wake' in bios
Turn The Screen Off: 10 mins
Dim Screen: On
Automatic Power Saver: On
Automatic Suspend: 90 minutes
Power Button Behaviour: switch off

Device Security Report (Few important ones):

BIOS Firmware Updates: ! Fail (Not Enabled)
Intel Management Engine Version:  ! Fail
TPM v2.0:  ! Fail (Not Found)
Suspend To RAM: ! Fail (Enabled)
Suspend To Idle:  ! Fail (Not Enabled)
Linux Swap: ! Fail (Not Encrypted)

Initially i had most of the crashes while restoring/Syncing data from a portable HDD which showed almost 24 hours to complete the sync/transfer. So on each crash i had to force shutdown and restart again.
I was able to transfer the data completely only after making those two changes in the bios.
I believe my laptop is running fine now. I shall post an update if the laptop crashes or freezes once again. Please correct me if i am wrong.
Thanks.

I also commented on How do I fix a Thinkpad P14s to wake from sleep?, and it may be a ThinkPad-specific solution, but for me, changing the "Sleep State" in BIOS fixed this (can be accessed by Config -> Power -> Sleep State in BIOS of the ThinkPad). My "Sleep State" state was in the "Linux S3" mode (which for some reason was already set for me), but I switched it to "Windows and Linux", and waking from sleep worked!
for reference, my system is:

Ubuntu 24.04
Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 10
kernel version: 6.8.0-39-generic


Not an answer to the question asked. Your fix only works for Lenovo.

I had the same issue on my Thinkpad L560 after upgrading to 24.04. It was solved by setting intel_iommu=off on the kernel command line (GRUB_CMDLINUX_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub and then update-grub)
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197029

I had the same issue on an Acer laptop when I changed from 22.04 (jammy) to 24.04 (noble). After some try and error what worked was:

Update the bios
Upgrade to 24.10 using the 6.8.0-45-generic kernel version. The 6.11.0-8-generic is failing to boot (it might be an isolated issue).
Change and update grub to use the kernel version that is working.
Install the driver nvidia-driver-560

After doing this the issue was gone.
24.10 Now Defaults To NVIDIA On Wayland and Nvidia's 560 driver seems to do a good job

This seems to be a bug with the current kernel in noble.
There is some useful information on Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2059738
For me it worked to use kernel 6.7 or 6.1.110. You can install them via the Ubuntu mainline archive. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

My solution was as follows:

Downgrade to an older kernel version (6.0, worked for me; I'm not sure whether slightly higher versions will work or not).
One can do so with the help of the mainline command.
a. Run sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa to add the repository.
b. Run sudo apt update to update the package list.
c. Run sudo apt install mainline to install the mainline tool.
d. To see the list of kernel versions available, you can run mainline list.
Now to install the actual kernel version, in this case version 6.0, one should run mainline install 6.0.

To test that everything works, you can reboot your PC, and just when it's starting up, press left Shift to access the grub menu. Select Advanced options for Ubuntu and then select the Kernel version we just installed (i.e. 6.0). You can then test to ensure that you are able to wake up from suspended mode by pressing the power button.
If everything works and you wish to set the newly installed kernel as the default kernel to boot with (seeing as the above procedure can be rather annoying), then try the following:

Run sudo grep 'menuentry' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Take note of the desired boot up kernel.
To specify your desired boot up kernel:
a. Run sudo nano /etc/default/grub to open the Grub config.
b. Locate the line GRUB_DEFAULT=0". c. Change it to point to the desired kernel. In our case, we change it to GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 6.0.0-06000-generic"(NB: the quotes are mandatory). c. Now, update grub by runningsudo update-grub. d. Finally, restart your computer. You can do so by simply running sudo reboot. c. Verify that you are indeed booting into Ubuntu with the desrired kernel by running uname -r`.

And... that's it. Hope this helps someone.

Just an update for the issue i had posted 6 months ago.
My Laptop is working fine now after all those regular software updates till now.
Didn't make any other change since May 2024.
Now i do get Force stop/wait messages when the Processor is fully utilized and these messages automatically disappear after a few seconds (Which is fine and expected in older hardware). System does not hang permanently, just like before !
So, i believe that bug has been rectified by software updates.
Thanks everyone for the replies.

The below package done the job for me, I am using ryzen 5 with AMD Radeon Graphics

sudo apt install gnome-screensaver

I was facing the issue on Ubuntu 22.04
even on the 24 latest version

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
